# Create a edit view in django to modify the existing issues

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have been trying to work out how to create a edit view in django but everything I try keeps on failing and not giving me the ability to edit the already saved objects.The issues get created fine and saved and displayed but I just cant load them for editing.The code is bellow any help or advice would be good.

views.py

```
class FormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'issuetracker/form.html'
    form_class = CreateIssueForm
    success_url = '/issue/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = Issue.objects.create(
            submitter=form.cleaned_data.get('submitter'),
            description=form.cleaned_data.get('description'),
            status=form.cleaned_data['status'],
            category=form.cleaned_data.get('category'),
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)


class IssueUpdateView(UpdateView):

    context_object_name = 'issue-update'
    form_class = CreateIssueForm
    template_name = 'issuetracker/update.html'
    success_url = 'issuetracker/issue_list.html'

    # get object
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    # override form_valid method
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # save cleaned post data
        clean = form.cleaned_data
        context = {}
        self.object = context.save(clean)
        return super(IssueUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    STATUS = (
        ('Assigned', 'Assigned'),
        ('Closed', 'Closed'),
    )
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Bug', 'Bug'),
        ('Enhancements', 'Enhancements'),
        ('Documentation', 'Documentation')
    )

    submitter = forms.CharField(required=False)
    solver = forms.CharField(required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=False)
    status = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,choices=STATUS)
    category = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,choices=CATEGORY)


        class Meta:
            model = Issue
            fields = ('submitter', 'solver', 'description','status','category')
```

models.py

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
    ('A', 'Assigned'),
    ('C', 'Closed'),
    )
    CATEGORY = (
        ('B', 'Bug'),
        ('E', 'Enhancements'),
        ('D', 'Documentation')
    )
    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    solver = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY)
    opened = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', StatView.as_view(), name='stat_view'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', IssueListView.as_view()),
url(r'^/create/$', FormView.as_view(), name='create_issue'),
url(regex=r'^issues/edit$',
    view= IssueUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='issue-update')
```

Comment: I see no code for editing an issue here... please edit your post to remove irrelevant code (we don't care about the issues list nor the stats) and add what you've tried (issue editing code) with details on _how_ it "failed" (full traceback etc).

Comment: The above was tried but does not load the objects into the update.html but it brings a blank for same as for new issue creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
class IssueUpdateView(UpdateView):
    # ...
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

I don't know why you're returning `request.user` here (could it be a copy-paste from some example you didn't fully understand ?) - but anyway:
`UpdateView.get_object()` is supposed to return the object to edit. You usually get this object from some unique id passed as argument from the url to the view:

```
url(regex=r'^issues/edit/(?P<issue_id>\d+)/$',
    view= IssueUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='issue-update')



class IssueUpdateView(UpdateView):
    # ...
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Issue.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["issue_id"])
```

Comment: Yes you are correct this was a copy paste as I do not understand how to do it.After trying your suggestion I got an error "Reverse for 'issue-update' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['issues/edit/(?P<issue_id>\\d+)/$'] "

Comment: You have to pass the issue id when reversing the url, of course, as documented. Copy-pasting code that you don't understand won't get you very far,  you'd better first take time to at least do the official tutorial and browse the doc. This will actually be faster than trying to do something, failing, searching SO, posting, waithing for an answer, copy-pasting the answer, lather rince repeat...

Comment: You are correct about that.I did go through the docs but I think Ill need a deeper read as this will something I will need again in the future.Thx for your help on this.